# Value sets in CDA

Tags: cda

Are the value sets defined by HL7 or it is the implementers who choose to define their own values? If HL7 sets defines value sets, are the implementers supposed to use only all or some of the value sets there, or they can add and modify the value sets as they see fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value sets can be defined by HL7, other SDO or locally, although, if you want your values to be understood outside your organization, SDO defined value sets are recommended.

HL7 defines values sets, and if you use them, only already defined values can be used.

Hope useful,
Martí

Comment: So, if I am using HL7, you can define and use your own value sets and do not have to use those defined by HL7 as part of the specification?

Comment: Yes, but you have to specify the OID of your value set instead of the one provided by the standard.